# Mac resize window below dock

Tags: macos, mac, dock

On my Macbook Pro running OS X 10.6.3 I can't resize a window below the top of the dock. That is, I can't drag (resize) the lower right corner of the window below the top of the dock. However, I can resize below the top of the dock on my iMac at work (also running OS X 10.6.3).  Note that I can drag the whole window such that the bottom goes below the dock.

Is there a setting to control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an external monitor connected to the iMac. The monitor's display goes below that of the iMac's. Thus it appears that OS X doesn't limit the downward resizing of windows.

Answer (score 11):

I fixed it by restarting my dock. Open the Terminal app and type `killall Dock`.

I think it's the dock getting into a bugged state; running this command restarts it and makes the dock behave correctly.

Comment: Exactly after running that command, I got this problem! -_-

Comment: This fixed the issue. I was using magnet app which uses shortcuts to change app window size, which wasn't working too. Now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Dock Preferences in System Preferences, just to be sure compare the two Macs' preferences.

It's most likely "Automatically hide and show the dock" checkbox.

Comment: Preferences are the same between the two machines.

Comment: Doesn't address the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue after I reboot my Macbook.  The solution that helped was toggling "Automatically hide and show the dock".  I also use Spectacle to move windows around and now it moves them to their proper location, above the dock.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to move the dock to the other monitor and back again.

I tried killing it like Cole had suggested, but when it restarted it was still behaving the same.

Note: My second monitor does not extend below the primary, but I still encountered the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. move the dock to a new position on the screen (bottom to left in my case)
2. grab the corner of an app and stretch down to the bottom of the screen
3. move the dock to its original position

I think any apps that were open when the dock was changed to auto hide cannot be resized to fill the dock space.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to achieve exactly what you want to disable: always show the dock and maximize windows respecting the dock. For me the dock was visible on top of maximized windows. After setting the dock to never hide and  issueing the killall Dock command and resizing the windows I got wat I was looking for.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).